# Yet another no module named *** with pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, pytest

Here is the project structure:

```
my_module/
├── pytest.ini
├── README
├── requirements.txt
├── my_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_module.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── helpers.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── logger.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── test_my_module.py
```

I don't understand why I get an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'utils'` when I run `pytest` in the root directory.

Here is the error

```sh
________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_robomaster.py _________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/heyyou/git/my_module/tests/test_my_module.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_my_module.py:3: in <module>
    from my_module import my_module
my_module/my_module.py:6: in <module>
    from utils import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

It works when I add an `__init__.py` at the root level (same as readme) but I don't think it's a good workaround.

The imports work if I run the `my_module.py` script directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do import like `from my_module.utils import *`. Because `pytest` insert `my_module` to the front of `sys.path`

Comment: problem is, now I can't run my module like this `python3 my_module/my_module.py` anymore because I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module.utils'; 'my_module' is not a package`

Comment: Run from root my_module folder  `python -m my_module.my_module`